# Access MySQL with IAM Role Authentication on Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services

I am currently working on enhancing the security of my WordPress site's database connection by shifting from password-based authentication to token-based authentication. My WordPress instance is dockerized, and we manage configuration variables and settings through a secret.yaml file. The goal is to utilize AWS SDK's capabilities for generating authentication tokens, leveraging IAM roles for a more secure connection to our MySQL database hosted on Amazon RDS.

**Current Setup:**

- Environment: Dockerized WordPress
- Database: MySQL on Amazon RDS
- Authentication: Direct connection using passwords

To improve security, I am considering defining our RDS endpoint, AWS region, and IAM username in the secret.yaml file, like so:

```
define('DB_IAM_ENDPOINT', 'your-rds-endpoint');
define('DB_IAM_REGION', 'your-aws-region');
define('DB_IAM_USERNAME', 'your-iam-username');
```

I plan to use the AWS SDK for PHP, which is already installed on our WordPress, to dynamically generate an authentication token. This token would then be used as a temporary password for database connections, offering a more secure alternative to static passwords.

**Question:**

How can I modify or adapt WordPress's database connection mechanism to authenticate using the generated token instead of a static password? Below is the PHP function I've devised for generating the token:

```
function createToken($endpoint, $region, $username) {
    $client = new Aws\Rds\RdsClient([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region' => $region,
    ]);
    $token = $client->generateDBAuthToken([
        'DBHostname' => $endpoint,
        'Port' => 3306,
        'DBUsername' => $username,
    ]);
    return $token;
}
```

I am planning to put this line to secret.yaml

```
define('DB_PASSWORD', createToken(DB_IAM_ENDPOINT, DB_IAM_REGION, DB_IAM_USERNAME));
```

Thank you in advance for your insights and assistance!